# Making Excel histograms using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel-formula, xlsxwriter

This is the output of my python script so far.
[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCQw1.png)

The vertical axis of the table are road names. The horizontal axis are dates. The values indicate if a road was under construction at the time and why. I'd like to make a line graph that groups the dates by years 2017, 2018, 2019 etc... and plots the longest amount a time within those groups that a road was under construction and the average amount for the whole year. I'm a complete novice in excel and don't know how to leverage it's features to achieve my goal, though I suspect that there may be built in functions that do what I want without much difficulty. Any suggestions on how can achieve my desired output would be much appreciated. EDIT: It was suggested that I post my code so far.

```
import re
import time
startTime = time.time()
import collections
import xlsxwriter as xlswr
import scipy.spatial as spy
from itertools import islice
from itertools import groupby
from natsort import natsorted
from functools import partial
from collections import Counter
from datetime import date as DATE
from indexed import IndexedOrderedDict
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import multiprocessing as mp

workBook = xlswr.Workbook("testfix.xlsx")
cell_format = workBook.add_format()
format1 = workBook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yy'})
sheet = workBook.add_worksheet()

def to_raw(string):
    return fr"{string}"

def cvrt(x):
    ans =  re.split(r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)', x)
    return int(ans[1])

def indexer(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r'I, [0-9]+, ')
    gm = re.split(pattern, s);
    values = s.rsplit(gm[1])
    gm = gm[1]
    values[1] = gm   
    return values
            
def int2Date(x):
    string = str(x)
    Y = int(string[0:4])
    M = int(string[4:6])
    D = int(string[6:8])
    return DATE(Y,M,D)

    
def dDelta(x, y):
    string1 = str(x)
    string2 = str(y)
    Y1 = int(string1[0:4])
    M1 = int(string1[4:6])
    D1 = int(string1[6:8])
    Y2 = int(string2[0:4])
    M2 = int(string2[4:6])
    D2 = int(string2[6:8])
    
    f_date = DATE(Y1,M1,D1)
    l_date = DATE(Y2,M2,D2)
    delta = l_date - f_date
    
    if isinstance(y, int):
        return float(int((delta.days)/30.44))
    else:
        return int((delta.days)/30.44)

      
def Book(path):
    file = open(path,'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    book = IndexedOrderedDict()

    for line in lines:
        if re.match("I", line):
           IDs = indexer(line)[1]
        
        if re.match("    0.00,", line):
           rID = line
           #"GM_FINAL_AUTH,0,[1-9]"
        if re.search("GM_FINAL_AUTH,0,[1-9]", line): 
           book.update({(rID, line): to_raw(IDs)})

    return sort_book(book)

def dUpdate(dic, key, value):
    return dic.update({(key[0], "GM_FINAL_AUTH,0,0"): value}) 

def valSplt(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
    gm = re.split(pattern, s)
    values = s.rsplit(gm[1])
    gm = gm[1]
    values[1] = gm   
    return values

def sort_book(book):
    book = natsorted([value, key] for key, value in book.items())
    book = IndexedOrderedDict((data[1], data[0]) for data in book)   
    return book 

def alph_order(word1, word2):
    for i in range(min(len(word1), len(word2))):
        if ord(word1[i]) == ord(word2[i]):
            pass
        elif ord(word1[i]) > ord(word2[i]):
            return word2
        else:
            return word1
    return word1

def read(cpdm, date_list):
    sCnt = [0] * len(cpdm)
    lowest_number = 999999999999
    terminationCondition = [True] * len(cpdm)
    saved_results = [0] * len(cpdm)
    current_prefix = None
    cnt = 0
    
    while any(terminationCondition) is True:
        saved_results = [0] * len(cpdm)
        last_prefix = None
        lowest_number = 999999999999
        for dicIdx, dicVal in enumerate(sCnt):
            if dicVal < len(cpdm[dicIdx]):
                ID = cpdm[dicIdx].values()[dicVal]
                # print(entry)
                current_prefix, road_number = valSplt(ID)
                road_number = int(road_number)
                if last_prefix is None:
                    last_prefix = current_prefix
                higherOrder_prefix = alph_order(last_prefix, current_prefix)
                # print('check:',[higherOrder_prefix, last_prefix, current_prefix])
                if current_prefix == higherOrder_prefix:
                    if current_prefix != last_prefix:
                        lowest_number = road_number
                        last_prefix = current_prefix
                    elif road_number < lowest_number:
                        lowest_number = road_number
                        last_prefix = current_prefix
    
    
        for dicIdx, dicVal in enumerate(sCnt):
            if dicVal < len(cpdm[dicIdx]):
                # print(dicIdx, dicVal, len(cpdm[dicIdx]))
                ID = cpdm[dicIdx].values()[dicVal]
                VALUE = cpdm[dicIdx].keys()[dicVal]
                # print(entry)
                road_name, road_number = valSplt(ID)
                road_number = int(road_number)
                if road_name == last_prefix and lowest_number == road_number:
                    saved_results[dicIdx] = [ID, VALUE[1], date_list[dicIdx], VALUE[0]]
                    if dicVal < len(cpdm[dicIdx]):
                        sCnt[dicIdx] += 1
                    else:
                        terminationCondition[dicIdx] = False
            else:
                terminationCondition[dicIdx] = False
        
        for rst in range(len(saved_results)):
            if saved_results[rst] == 0:
                pass
            else:
                sheet.write(cnt+1, 0, str(saved_results[rst][0]))
                sheet.write(cnt+1, rst+1, cvrt(saved_results[rst][1]))
                #sheet.write(cnt+1, 2*et+3, int2Date(saved_results[et][2]), format1)
                #sheet.write(cnt+1, 0, saved_results[rst][3])
                
        cnt += 1      


def main(): 
    # 2018 MAPS
    path1 = "W:\\Scripting\\2018\\DBData_84577881.txt"
    path2 = "W:\\Scripting\\2018\\DBData_84639568.txt"
    path3 = "W:\\Scripting\\2018\\DBData_84652483.txt"
    path4 = "W:\\Scripting\\2018\\DBData_84670490.txt"
    
    # 2019 MAPS
    path5 = "W:\\Scripting\\2019\\DBData_84706383.txt"
    path6 = "W:\\Scripting\\2019\\DBData_84715201.txt"
    path7 = "W:\\Scripting\\2019\\DBData_84743195.txt"
    path8 = "W:\\Scripting\\2019\\DBData_84777742.txt"
    path9 = "W:\\Scripting\\2019\\DBData_84815446.txt"
    path10 = "W:\\Scripting\\2019\\DBData_84835743.txt"
    
     # 2020 MAPS
    path11 = "W:\\Scripting\\2020\\DBData_84882849.txt"
    path12 = "W:\\Scripting\\2020\\DBData_84966202.txt"
    path13 = "W:\\Scripting\\2020\\DBData_84988789.txt"
    
    p_list = [path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7,
              path8, path9, path10, path11, path12, path13]


    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    CPDM = pool.map(Book, p_list)
    pool.close()    
    #pool.join()
    
    date_list = [20180809, 20180913, 20181011, 20181204, 20190222, 20190325,
                 20190501, 20190628, 20190815, 20190925, 20200207, 20200501, 20200617]
    

    #CPDM = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13]
  
    for i in CPDM:
        print(len(i))

    #sheet.write("A1", "Lat Long")
    sheet.write("A1", "ID")
    #for i in range(len(CPDM)):
    cn = 0
    for i in date_list:
        #sheet.write(0, 3*i+1, "ID" + str(i+1))
        sheet.write(0, cn+1, int2Date(i), format1)
        cn += 1
        #sheet.write(0, 2*i+3, "Date" + str(i+1))
        
    read(CPDM, date_list)
    workBook.close() 
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    
executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)
print('Execution time in minutes: ' + str(executionTime/60))
```

Comment: You should also post your script

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, what you want is not exactly possible. Your data contains spot measurements, so what happened in between? Or after? Was the road under construction or not? This makes it impossible to calculate an accurate number of days that the road was under construction.

It is possible to do something that approximates what you want, but that will require some choices from your side. For example, if you measure that the road is under construction on 08/15/2019 but not anymore on 05/01/2020, do you count all the days between those 2 dates as closed? Or only until new years?

To help you get started I've added a little script that does some formatting on your data. It should give you an idea of how to handle the data.

```py
import pandas
import plotly.express as px

# Read the Excel file
df = pandas.read_excel("./test.xlsx", index_col="ID")

# Flip the dataframe (dates should be on the index)
df = df.transpose()

# Fill any empty cells with 0
df = df.fillna(0)

# Combine columns with the same name
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda column: column.max(axis=1))

# Make sure the dates are sorted
df = df.sort_index()

# Create a list to hold all the periods per road
roads = []
for road_name in df.columns:

    # Group by consecutive 1's
    groups = df.loc[df[road_name] == 1, road_name].groupby((df[road_name] != 1).cumsum())

    # Every group denotes a period for which the road was under construction
    for _, group in groups:

        # Get the start and finish for each group
        roads.append({
            "road": road_name,
            "start": group.index[0],
            "finish": group.index[-1] + pandas.Timedelta(1, unit="D"),  # Add one day because groups with same start and finish will not be visible on the plot
        })

# Convert back to a dataframe
roads_df = pandas.DataFrame(roads)

# Create a Gantt chart with Plotly (NOTE: you'll need version 4.9+ of Plotly)
fig = px.timeline(roads_df, x_start="start", x_end="finish", y="road")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")  # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

[image: Gantt chart]

Comment: Thank you, this was a great starting point for me! I've been looking into the documentation on Pandas and Plotly, and now have an Idea on how to move forward.